# If/Else Nested in While loop in Javascript Not Looping

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

As it is written, the function is only returning a single line of the song.  "number" is a number inputted by the user.  How do I get it to continue through the while loop until it gets to 0?  I've played around with where to decrement the number (in the while condition, in each if statement, etc) but that doesn't seem to matter.  Thanks for any feedback! Edited to show as array instead of string.

```
 var theFunction = function(number) {
  var song = [];
  while(number > 0){
    if(number > 2) {
      song.push(number + "lyrics in song.");
      number--;
    } else if(number === 2) {
      song.push(number + "different lyrics in song");
      number--;
    } else if(number === 1) {
      song.push(number + " other lyrics");
      number--;
    } else {
      song.push("End of song");
    }
    return song;
  };
};
```

Comment: Do you want to return a list of songs instead of one song?

Comment: `var songs = [];`... `songs.push("...")` ... `return songs;`

Comment: What's the point of assigning the same variable each time through the loop? The final value of `song` will just be the value from the last iteration.

Comment: Yes, I actually did want an array (it's a list of lyrics in a song)!  But even when I changed it to an array, it's still only looping once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such magic that by putting `return` inside loop, you can get a list of return values. If you want that, you have to construct the list explicitly.

`return` means: Stop further execution immediately because I already know what needs to be returned. And here it is.

```
var theFunction = function(number) {
  var song = [];
  while(number > 0){
    if(number > 2) {
      song.push(number + "lyrics in song.");
    } else if(number === 2) {
      song.push(number + "different lyrics in song");
    } else if(number === 1) {
      song.push(number + " other lyrics");
    } else {
      song.push("End of song");
    }
    number--;
  }
  return song;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  I had the return statement in the wrong spot.  It should be:

```
var theFunction = function(number) {
  var song = [];
  while(number > 0){
    if(number > 2) {
      song.push(number + "lyrics in song.");
      number--;
    } else if(number === 2) {
      song.push(number + "different lyrics in song");
      number--;
    } else if(number === 1) {
      song.push(number + " other lyrics");
      number--;
    } else {
      song.push("End of song");
    }
  } return song;
};
```

Comment: Don't put things on the same line as `}` unless it's an inline function definition.